# Call js function from external file Symfony Twig

Tags: javascript, symfony, twig, symfony4

I'm having issues calling functions from twig views in Symfony 4.4. This view is called ***UserList.html.view*** and it extends ***base.html.twig***

The beginning of the file is as following :

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
{% block body %}
{% block javascripts %}
    <script src="{{ asset('build/js/custom.js') }}"></script>
...
```

I also tried with Encore by adding an entry but it's not working. The only way to access external functions is to call them from the parent view which is not what I want obviously.

The error I get :

> Uncaught ReferenceError: coucou is not defined
>       at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (VM3883 manageAccounts:183)
>   onclick @ VM3883 manageAccounts:183

I read some other posts about this but none of them actually provided a working solution.

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope everyone is doing great during this troubles times ! France started containment last week so I had plenty of time finding the solution.

Dumbest thing ever but I didn't know that..

In your js external files, you have to declare your functions like this :

```
window.myfunction = function myfonction(){}
```

That's all..

Could that potentialy cause security issues ? I don't know so I'm asking xD

Answer (score 0):

Hello there and welcome to SO forums. It is hard to put a finger on your issue based on the provided pieces of code - but the twig block usage might be something that is not implemented / working as you assume. Namely the javascript block inside the implemented body block has no relevancy to the a similarly named block in base template (I assume that there is similarly named block there) because it is placed inside the body block which you are completely overwriting in this `UserList.html.twig` template.

A basic working twig structure would be something like this:

base.html.twig

```
<html>
    <head>
        ...
    </head>
    <body>
        ...
        {% block body %}
            ...
        {% endblock %}
        ...
        {% block javascripts %}
           ...
        {% endblock %}
        ...
    </body>
</html>
```

UserList.html.twig - please note the `parent()` call that makes sure that the block contents from the inherited template are included as well (i.e. if you have some generic jquery or some other generic js includes defined there) - without the `parent()` you will be defining the javascripts block contents completely again in this template.

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
   ...
{% endblock %}

{% block javascripts %}
   {{ parent() }}
   <script src="{{ asset('build/js/custom.js') }}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Hello, Thank for this answer ;) I cannot provide more than that unfortunetly :/ What I noticed is that I can see the file in Sources under chrome when I go on the page that includes this view. But still no way to call any functions from it. I do have Jquery and that's why I call parent()